# confused on electrical circuit, 2-wire 240v

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

new to us home and I found a recessed junction box in the closet where the upstairs furnace is located. 2 wires, white/black with ground. metered it and 240v, but when I thought I had the correct corresponding breaker and turned it off, meter read 315v. Older home so the breaker index has too many scratch thru's to know every circuit. trying to understand this one but may be beyond my homeowner electrical knowledge

Comment: Quite a few 240 circuits use the white wire as a second hot, that is okay(white wire should have black tape on it).  Turning off the breaker should give 0v or if wrong breaker 240v.  315v is very weird.  Add type of furnace, since most are only 120 except if they heat electrically.

Comment: @crip659  I have to politely disagree with your comment that most furnaces are 120 v. If just a simple air handler, maybe, but if part of a heat pump system with backup resistance heating, NO WAY.  It will need a couple of 240 v circuits just for the "furnace" AKA air handler.   If a gas furnace, you are probably right, they don't need much power.   But people use the term "furnace" to describe a variety of units.  We need to know the config, to be able to give good advice.

Comment: Thanks! The furnace runs on a 240v 60amp circuit but does not appear to be any connection to the circuit in question (its own breaker in a separate panel). Yes furnace is the blower part of a heat pump system plus the emergency heat. If I turn off the 60 amp furnace breaker the furnace is off and no relationship to circuit in question

Comment: and some additional clarification, the circuit in question was wire nut capped inside the j box on the second floor, panels in basement

Comment: Bob, how and where are you measuring the voltage? As @george Anderson mentioned we need more info the actual fact is if you use ground as a reference in the U.S. you will never measure more than 120v to the line, but there is a case if the motor s in the circuit it can act as an auto transformer and you can measure much higher voltages line to line provides 240 as everyone knows but to measure a higher value points to trouble in some cases or a single leg switch in a 240v circuit that has a motor.